# Data structure / algorithm for information retrieval system

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, information-retrieval

I have a task with condition below - it's regarding Java / Data structures. I will try to put my questions briefly as answering these will help me find the way (as I am lost):

1. What is the data structure you'd suggest to be used?
2. What algorithm would you follow? (details appreciated).

Simple information retrieval system where a query contains keywords and 
there is a collection of documents to be searched. In response to a query, the system 
identifies each document (up to a maximum of n documents) that contains all or some 
keywords and prints document names in descending order of keywords found, i.e. a 
document that contains all keywords should appear at the top of the list.

Answer (score 5):

First, you might be looking for [**apache lucene**](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), which is an open source library that implements IR system, in java!

Implementing something on your own is hard, but the most important data structure in IR is an [**inverted index**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

The inverted index is actually a `map:term->list<index>`, that maps between each term to the documents it appears in. The advantage of inverted index - is it fits well IR standard ops, such as conjunction (and query).

In your specific question, build an inverted index from the collection, and once a query of `k` terms arrives - get the `k` lists corresponding to these terms, and get their union.

Now, once you have the union - all is left is to create a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) (in how many lists each term appear, can be implemented as [`HashMap<Term,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) - and print the keys of these histogram in descending value order.

If you want to extend your knowledge on IR, I recommend reading Manning's [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, Amit. HashMap is a good starting point and the book too (I have seen it but hadn't got much time to read but it looks like that's the right one:)As I am a bit limited by time just needed something to point me straight to useful and take it from there.